# Error while calling ClientContext.ExecuteQuery() in Sharepoint 2013 CSOM

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, csom

I am new to sharepoint and trying to learn CSOM. I have written a simple code in a console application using VS 2012 to get list details from a sharepoint 2013 site:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential("xxxx", "xxxx", "xxxx");
            ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://xxxxxxxxxx-vm2:6667/");
            context.Credentials = credentials;
            List list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("SchoolsList");
            context.Load(list);
            context.ExecuteQuery();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

On *context.ExecuteQuery();* I am getting an error: **An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions xxx.xx.xx.xx:6667**
[image]
Could someone please let me know what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that firewall/antivirus doesn't block this address or port